Unable to filter and sort multiple columns with this filter/sort/map function?
I have a function that joins in columns from multiple sheets, concatenates comments and brings in maximum value from "statuses" sheet.
I want the ability to click on my headers and sort column A, and then go and sort another column and more if I need to. I currently only have the ability to sort by one column with this:
=sort( 
  filter( 
    hstack( 
      choosecols('Raw Data'!A3:Z,5,21,4,3,9), 
      iferror(map('Raw Data'!D3:D, lambda(Σ, if(Σ="",,textjoin(char(10),1,sort(filter({TEXT(Comments!C:C,"m/d/yy : ")&Comments!B:B},Comments!A:A=Σ),filter(Comments!C:C,Comments!A:A=Σ),))))),""), 
      xlookup('Raw Data'!D3:D,Statuses!A:A,Statuses!B:B,,,-1), choosecols('Raw Data'!A3:Z,6,23,7,11,1,2) 
    ), 
    'Raw Data'!A3:A <> "" 
  ), 
  column(E1), false  
)

Is there a way to add in all columns in column(E1), false  sort of like columns(1:13),false ?
Link to sheet is here and the formula is in cell A2.
Again, I want the ability to sort and filter any number of columns in sequence that I want just like I would with a normal worksheet. Is this even possible?

I haven't found a way to add that automatically, but I propose you this workaround that sorts the range by each column with the help of REDUCE and a decreasing sequence of numbers of columns:
=REDUCE( 
  filter( 
    hstack( 
      choosecols('Raw Data'!A3:Z,5,21,4,3,9), 
      Iferror(map('Raw Data'!D3:D, lambda(Σ, if(Σ="",,textjoin(CARACTER(10),1,sort(filter({TEXT(Comments!C:C,"m/d/yy : ")&Comments!B:B},Comments!A:A=Σ),filter(Comments!C:C,Comments!A:A=Σ),))))),""), 
      XLOOKUP('Raw Data'!D3:D,Statuses!A:A,Statuses!B:B,,,-1), choosecols('Raw Data'!A3:Z,6,23,7,11,1,2) 
    ), 
    'Raw Data'!A3:A <> "" 
  ),SEQUENCE(13,1,13,-1),
LAMBDA(a,v,SORT(a,v,FALSE)))



UPDATE TO ADD HEADERS
=VSTACK(
HSTACK(choosecols('Raw Data'!A1:Z1,5,21,4,3,9),"Comments","Status",choosecols('Raw Data'!A1:Z1,6,23,7,11,1,2)),
REDUCE( 
  filter( 
    hstack( 
      choosecols('Raw Data'!A3:Z,5,21,4,3,9), 
      IFERROR(map('Raw Data'!D3:D, lambda(Σ, IF(Σ="",,textjoin(CHAR(10),1,sort(filter({TEXT(Comments!C:C,"m/d/yy : ")&Comments!B:B},Comments!A:A=Σ),filter(Comments!C:C,Comments!A:A=Σ),))))),""), 
      XLOOKUP('Raw Data'!D3:D,Statuses!A:A,Statuses!B:B,,,-1), choosecols('Raw Data'!A3:Z,6,23,7,11,1,2) 
    ), 
    'Raw Data'!A3:A <> "" 
  ),SEQUENCE(13,1,13,-1),
LAMBDA(a,v,SORT(a,v,FALSE))))



Hey, thank you! So if you go back into the sheet, you can see that I tried sorting column A and it offsets the rows further down the sheet?

I was offering a sorting inside the formula, you're trying also to sort with the filters in the headers?

correct, is it even possible to sort within the headers because the formula moved when you do?

I added an option that stacks the headers from the columns you've got and the rest of the formulas. Consider that you won't be able to sort by the green icons in each of the columns, but you'll be able to use them for filtering. You should delete all the headers, and put the formula in A1, like I show in the picture and in your sheet
